# Can plasma be formed entirely by ions?

Tags: charge, plasma-physics, states-of-matter, ions

Plasma can be formed by an altogether combination of ions, free electrons, atoms, and molecules. Searching a little bit on the internet I found that plasma can't be formed entirely by electrons, because they will fly apart. I wanted to know if plasma can be formed by ions only, as in, cations and anions, but no free electrons or neutral atoms/molecules.

Edit: Seems like [electron plasma](http://www.ipr.res.in/nnp/) are also possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle this is achievable, and is known as an *ion-ion*, or simply an [*ion* plasma](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S016943320700195X). In practice (that is, in the lab), however, there is always some small level of contamination, which may or may not be meaningful. [Have a look at this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5109805), where a hydrogen ionic plasma with a fractional electron concentration of $n_e/n_{+} \sim 10^{-2}$ is produced via the use of a control grid for electron removal. The resulting ionic plasma is composed *almost purely* of negative and positive ions, containing molecular ions.